# JBoss Drools verifier with custom evaluators

Tags: jboss, drools

I am using JBoss Drools verifier to verify rule files.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-verifier</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0.Final</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In the rule file, I uses some of the custom evaluators like the below

```
KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration builderConf = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration();

            builderConf.setOption(EvaluatorOption.get("int", (EvaluatorDefinition) Class.forName("com.company.evaluators.IntEvaluatorDefinition").newInstance()));
```

The rule Verifier does not understand these custom evaluators and throw errors. Is there any simple way to pass these custom evaluators information to the verifier ? I am using the following code -

```
 verifier.addResourcesToVerify(ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource (in),
                                   ResourceType.DRL);


    verifier.fireAnalysis();

    //Get the Verifier errors   
    List<VerifierError> errors = verifier.getErrors();

    if ( errors.size() > 0 ) {
        System.out.println("####### Verifier Errors #############");
        for (VerifierError error : errors) {
            System.out.println(error.getMessage());
        }
    }else {
        // Get the result object [5]
        VerifierReport result = verifier.getResult();

        // Print the the errors [6]
        for(VerifierMessageBase base: result.getBySeverity( Severity.ERROR ) ){
            System.out.println( base );
        }
        for(VerifierMessageBase base: result.getBySeverity( Severity.NOTE) ){
            System.out.println( base );
        }
        for(VerifierMessageBase base: result.getBySeverity( Severity.WARNING) ){
            System.out.println( base );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like I need to add support for them. Thanks for reporting. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3419

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the best way, but try setting them as system properties:

```
drools.evaluator.<ident> = <qualified class>
```

E.g., when executing the verifier, use in the command line

```
java -Ddrools.evaluator.int=com.company.evaluators.IntEvaluatorDefinition ...
```